# Unused variable in python enumerate

Tags: python, list, enumerate

Im using enumerate to obtain the indexes in a list ("i"), but I don't need the value of every element ("j"). "j" is unused in my code, so this is a warning in the eclipse IDE. How I can fix this?

Code:

```
for i,j in enumerate(my_list):
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(my_list)):`...

Comment: This question is unclear. What is it exactly you are trying to do? What exactly is the error that you are seeing? Please provide a working example that reproduces the error.

Comment: What @WillemVanOnsem said or `for i, _ in enumerate(my_list)` if you are talking about a warning by your IDE

Comment: @schwobaseggl: this is indeed semantically equivalent, but less efficient since here you do not do tuple packing, unpacking, reference counting, etc.

Comment: I just edited the question with a little more clarity

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am aware. But as a general remark as there are other cases where you do not use a value that is returned by a function, e.g. `instance, _ = Foo.objects.get_or_create(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the index, you can use:

```
my_index = [i for i in range(len(mylist))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just because an IDE gives you a warning that doesn't mean you have to change your code. @WillemVanOnsem gives you the necessary solution to iterating over the indexes in his comment.